# Recover files from failed raid 0

Tags: partitioning, ssd, raid, data-recovery

I have a client whose laptop (Asus GX502) stopped working, and as I fix the laptop he wants his data from his drives, but problem is that when I connected the nvme SSDs (512 GB each) to my test computer, it shows up as a single partition of 1 TB, and to access it I have to format it. I am assuming the configuration is in raid 0. I tried booting from the raid, but it says no bootable device found when I do that. I used a program called reclaime raid recovery to reconstruct the raid, but it says that no raid was detected. I tried a different program called R-Studio, I created a virtual raid, added the two disks to it, and when I try to open the raid it gives me the following error: Virtual Block Raid 1: GPT tables error 0x224.

Can someone please help me get the files?

Comment: RAID 0 is always a bad idea when using any data that cannot be easily reproduced. To even begin to answer the question we need a bit more information. Is there a hardware raid controller involved? Is this Windows or Linux and how was the raid configured? You will certainly need the exact same hardware/software setup as on the client's laptop to access the array. Please emphasize to you client that raid is not backup and that raid0 doubles your odds of data loss.

Comment: if you're doing this for a client you should out-source this to a data recovery specialist.

Comment: "my test computer, it shows up as a single partition of 1 TB" - add a disk management screenshot of that.

Comment: So Intel Rapid Storage Technology showed me that they are indeed in Raid0, in a failed state, and with stripe size 128. I used that information to reconstruct the raid in R-Studio, and unfortunately it turns out the drive is encrypted with Windows' Bitlocker, and sadly the client does not have the encryption key. Thank you all for the help.